# Custom switch button using textView

Tags: android, xml, layout, textview

I created custom switch button using two textview components. Is there any easy way to give one element on the another using OnClickListener ?
 Example:

[image]

Comment: You can use SwitchCompatLibrary to use Switch element in older versions of Android : https://github.com/ankri/SwitchCompatLibrary . Or in my opinion just use Button with two backrounds and align programmatically it's text to left / right in onClick .

Comment: I needn't use this library because I made custom switcher, only one problem is described above.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you make your own? Android already provides [Switches](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/switches.html) where you don't have to worry about any of this stuff since it is already implemented. Specifically you want the [Toggle Button](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html) (changes to a switch button in Android 4.0+).

This way you will be providing users controls which are specific to their platform and match other similar applications that they use.

Comment: I must implemented custom switcher (rounded corner, custom background color, custom font etc.), above image is only example. I have only one problem: I don't know how can I give one textView on the another ...

Comment: You would want to use a relative layout. That is not a normal component on the Android platform. Implementing it will cause you additional development time and support. The components provided with Android have been fully tested, work with multiple screen sizes, and are able to handle user preferences such as custom Text Size and Fonts already.

Comment: I made this component but the only one problem is how to give one textView above another after click the textView ?